# React Native: React Navigation: Using "setOptions" to set options outside of screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

In React Navigation, we can change the `options` property of a Screen using `navigation.setOptions({ /* new options */ })` inside this screen.

```
<Stack.Screen name="Custom" component={CustomScreen} options={{ title:  'Custom' /* Using "setOptions" will change this */ }} />
```

But in my case, I don't want to modify the `options` of the Screen I am in but the `screenOptions` of the Navigator the Screen is inside:

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: true /* For example, changing this to false */ }}>
  <Stack.Screen name="Custom" component={CustomScreen} options={{ title:  'Custom' }} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by that? `screenOptions` is just the default `options` for screens. If you want to change default options for the whole navigator then there's no method for that. You need to use some state and React context to update it

Comment: It problem is basically even harder, I wanted to hide tab headers onClick and the param to hide the tab headers is in the tab.navigator, not the tab screen. But I guess its just not possible so I just wrapped the tab navigator in a stack navigator and then navigated to another stack to "hide" the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

***Step 1:*** Import `NavigationContext`

```
import { NavigationContext } from "@react-navigation/native";
```

***Step 2:*** create reference of navigation context

```
const navigation = useContext(NavigationContext);
```

***Step 3:*** Update the options

```
 useEffect(() => {
    navigation?.setOptions({
      title: "Create Contact",
    });
  }, []);
```